# Meteor : Countdown timer

Tags: meteor

This might be a big ask, but I'm completely stuck so any help is appreciated.

I'm trying to create a countdown timer that runs from Sunday to Sunday and just restarts at the end of the week. I've tried using countdown packages in atmosphere but the documentation is limited and never seems to work. I've also tried to download and run 3rd party jquery packages however they always seem to crash meteor.

Could someone point me in the right direction or show me how to do this in meteor?

**Specific details:**

- Countdown timer used to run an auction.
- Auction runs for 7 days, Starts Sunday at 12:00am finishes 7 days
  later.
- Auction resets and starts again after 7 days.
- Countdown timer will be visible by users on multiple pages.
- Countdown timer units to be displayed - Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds (eg.
  6 days, 3 hours, 55 minutes, 22 seconds until the next auction
  begins.)

Comment: What is the unit of the timer? per day, hour, minutes, sec ? does the data need to be reactive ?

Comment: Day, hour, minute, sec would be great. I'm not sure what you mean by reactive. The timer will start on Sunday and end on Sunday, then start again.

Comment: you need to be more specific about your idea. What data need to be displayed? what is the unit ? because based on the unit, the code could be changed. Also, does the data need to be displayed or just to save into mongo?

Comment: Thanks @ThaiTran . I've updated it above. Is that the type of information you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is too large. But i can suggest the small step to work with this. Your auction scheme will need to have a `endDateTime` to store the value (even it will start/end in Sunday). On the template you need to display the timer, set one `ReactiveVar` as number (to count down), one `ReactiveVar` as string (to display to result)

```
Template['countDownTemplate'].created = function() {
    var due, dueDate, duration, now, num, self;
    self = this;

    dueDate = Template.instance().data['auction']['endDateTime'];
    now = moment.utc();

    due = moment.utc(dueDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');

    duration = moment.duration(due.diff(now));
    num = Math.floor(duration.asSeconds());

    if (num >= 0) {
        self['remaining'] = new ReactiveVar<number>(num);
        self['timeRemaining'] =  new ReactiveVar<string>(convertPeriod(num));
        self['interval'] = Meteor.setInterval((function() {
            var remaining;
            remaining = self['remaining'].get();
            self['remaining'].set(remaining - 1);
            self['timeRemaining'].set(convertPeriod(self['remaining'].get()));
            if (remaining === 0) {
                Meteor.clearInterval(self['interval']);
            } else {
                remaining = Math.floor(moment.duration(due.diff(now)).asSeconds());
            }
        }), 1000);
    }
};
```

(the `convertPeriod` will be based on the `remaining` number to convert into your correct format)

The rest is just about showing `timeRemaining` in the correct format with the `convertPeriod`

Comment: Thanks Thai, I'll give this a try and see how I go.